# Error for more than one value in subquery even thought its in a while loop

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The goal for the procedure is to:
Check service can be preformed on model (input modelID and serviceID) and get budget for the service plus the parts used. The way our tables are set up means we have to find the PartID with the PartName the service specifies is needed for the service. The same name for partname could in theory recur an infinite number of times. So the PartID's we get we need to check if they are compatible with the model (we assume that there is only one partname for each model IE ending in one ID).
Then getting the price for that PartID and multiplying it with the amount specified in service and adding the service price to it.

We have tried to fix the more then one row in a subquery with a while loop but for some weird reason that we cannot see it still complains about it. The procedure we are trying to make and get to work is this one:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `BudgetSpec`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE BudgetSpec (IN GetSpecServiceID MEDIUMINT, IN GetModelID MEDIUMINT)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS partid_tempt;
    CREATE temporary table partid_tempt (ID MEDIUMINT NOT NULL auto_increment, PartID MEDIUMINT, primary key(id)) engine = innodb;
    SET @SpecSerCheck = (SELECT SScbpoMID FROM specificservicescanbepreformedonmodel WHERE SpecServiceID = GetSpecServiceID AND ModelID = GetModelID);
    if @SpecSerCheck IS NOT NULL then
        SET @Part_name = (SELECT PartName FROM specificservice_amount WHERE SpecServiceID = GetSpecServiceID);
        INSERT INTO partid_tempt (PartID)
        SELECT PartID FROM part WHERE PartName = @Part_name;
        SET @v_counter = 1;
        SET @v_max = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM partid_tempt) + 1;
        start transaction;
        while @v_counter < @v_max do
            SET @PM_ID = (SELECT PcwMID FROM partcombatiablewithmodel WHERE ModelID = GetModelID AND PartID IN (SELECT PartID FROM partid_tempt WHERE ID = @v_counter));
            if @PM_ID IS NOT NULL then
                SET @v_counter = @v_max;
            end if;
            SET @v_counter = @v_counter + 1;
        end while;
        commit;
        if @PM_ID IS NOT NULL then
            SET @Part_price_n = (SELECT Part_ValuePrice FROM part_value WHERE PartID = @id AND ConditionID = 1);
            SET @Part_price_u = (SELECT Part_ValuePrice FROM part_value WHERE PartID = @id AND ConditionID = 2);
            SET @SS_price = (SELECT SpecService_ValuePrice FROM specificservice_value WHERE SpecServiceID = GetSpecServiceID);
            SET @SS_amount = (SELECT SpecService_Amount FROM specificservice_amount WHERE SpecServiceID = GetSpecServiceID);
            SET @S_sum_n = @SS_price + @Part_price_n * @SS_amount;
            SET @S_sum_u = @SS_price + @Part_price_u * @SS_amount;
            SELECT 'Service price with new part:', @S_sum_n;
            SELECT 'Service price with used part:', @S_sum_u;
        end if;
    end if;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

We wouldn't ask for help if it wasn't because we have run out of ideas to fix it and could really use some new input. Our database can be found at: [The most reason build of our DB is in the branch "Only_mysql"](https://github.com/KEA-BEIT/ERAC-DB).

Comment: Can you add the exact error and indicate for which line the error occurs?

Comment: CALL budgetspec(1,1);
/* SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row */

Comment: Without knowing on which line this is occurring my suspicion is that it is occurring for the one of the queries for one of the SETs, which require one value resultsets. Have you tried running the individual queries with your specified input and see which returns more than one row?

Comment: Ran all selects though individually and found that it was the sentence:
SET @SS_price = (SELECT....). So I added a Limit 0,1 in the end and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the idea to run them individually. :)

Comment: Not knowing what your need is here: consider adding DISTINCT instead of LIMIT in case all values are expected to be the same and you would prefer an error to randomly choosing one value of many.